# How to pass the Classic ASP Response Object to a C# DLL

Tags: c#, asp-classic, vbscript, httpresponse

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to pass the Response object from classic asp to a C# class library and if so how it is done.

I'm using C# 2010 express and JScript in ASP, but I'll take a VBScript answer.

Or if there is another way of outputting to the http context of the classic asp page from a dll, that'll also do.

I thinking that it can't be done as the System.Web.HttpResponse object doesn't seem to be available from a class library.

Thank you to those who responded.  By way of a complete answer for anybody else that may have the same question, here is some sample code:

```
public string passObj(ASPTypeLibrary.Response r)
{
    r.Write("text from DLL");
    return "OK";
}
```

and on the classic asp side of things:

```
var x = Server.CreateObject("dllTest.test");
x.passObj(Response);
```

Comment: The whole object, or just some part of it, like the query string?

Comment: The whole object, I want to use it in my dll to output to the http context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the classic ASP objects including Response, you can add a COM reference in your C# project to "Microsoft Active Server Pages Object Library".

You can then reference it from C# as:

```
ASPTypeLibrary.Response
```

Comment: So would this be the same response object that the calling ASP page is using and if not does it make any difference?

Comment: It seems I can pass it in as an ASPTypeLibrary.Response and then use the methods found in the IResponse interface OR I can do: ASPTypeLibrary.Response response = (ASPTypeLibrary.Response)ContextUtil.GetNamedProperty("Response");

Answer (score 1):

The Response object is a [COM object that supports IUnknown and IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525848%28v=vs.90%29). Therefore, you can pass it to a method as an object and call the properties using reflection.

From looking on my own machine, the `IReponse IID` is `{D97A6DA4-D5F5-4763-9BE5-60126DD39E43}`
Typelib UUID is `{A79CBB28-1006-4227-BE61-CBEE2520C353}`. If you open regedit and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{A79CBB28-1006-4227-BE61-CBEE2520C353}\2.0\0\win32` the default key will contain a path to the Typelib you can import to create the interop assembly.